# Update column with a prefix in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to update a column with a prefix (**HT_**) to an existing value.

I have this update-statement in MySQL

```
UPDATE users SET mail = 'HT_{current value of user_mail}'
```

Example:

**info@wibergsweb** should be updated to **HT_info@wibergsweb.se**

Can I use `REPLACE()` for this? How? Can someone give me a pointer/hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `CONCAT()`

```
UPDATE users SET mail = CONCAT('HT_', mail, '.se')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfbb41/1)